# I couldn't install dropbox

Tags: windows-8.1, dropbox

Whenever I install Dropbox on Windows 8.1, the setup wizard will suddenly disappear after asking permission to install. I have tried to install Dropbox through the Windows Store previously. Did anyone face this problem too? Is there a way where I can install Dropbox?

Comment: Have you any previous versions of the application installed? Try removing them. Have you the prerequisites for the program installed? Install them if necessary... Finally, to help us, can you tag your question with what OS you are trying to install DropBox client to...

Comment: I didn't install any previous version of dropbox, I am using window 8.1. But I did install dropbox application from the window store, will that affect the desktop version of dropbox?

Comment: @Ivan - Try removing that first then reinstall.  I assume you have the required persmissions to install applications?

Comment: @Ramhound It wouldn't close out if he didn't. It would give some error. OP: Try right-clicking and choosing `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: I want to re install the application now, but it even worse, when I press on the .exe file, it didn't show anything up.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer and re-run the installer?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - I tried to install as Administrator, but it then pop out a dialogue said: Dropbox will not work correctly if installed using the "Run as Administrator" command.

Comment: Yes, I did restart my computer and re run the installer, but it didn't show anything.

Comment: The Dropbox forums have a possible solution to run the installer with compatibility settings: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201468599-Can-only-install-with-Run-as-administrator-possibly-causing-sync-ing-problems

Comment: Odd that it doesn't work without compatibility - it probably does and there's something not quite right with your install... but only a clean install of the OS will provide a true answer...

Comment: What do you mean by clean install of the OS?

Comment: Are you installing the desktop or App Store version?

Comment: The desktop version